Android Kotlin Infotainment app with ROOM DB - error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object)
I am new to Android infotainment app development, I am storing the data in DB and get the data from DB and place the data in Google maps using PlaceListMapTemplate.
Can we use Room database in Android Automative ?

below is my LocationEntity DB class,
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "locations")
data class LocationEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val radius: Float
)

below is my Interface LocationDao,
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface LocationDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertLocation(location: LocationEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM locations")
    suspend fun getAllLocations(): List<LocationEntity>
}

below is my app database class,
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [LocationEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun locationDao(): LocationDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "GMADDA"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}

Below is the LocationRepository,
class LocationRepository(private val locationDao: LocationDao) {

    suspend fun insertLocation(location: LocationEntity) {
        locationDao.insertLocation(location)
    }

    suspend fun getAllLocations(): List<LocationEntity> {
        return locationDao.getAllLocations()
    }
}

below is the LocationViewModel,
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class LocationViewModelFactory(private val repository: LocationRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LocationViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return LocationViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

below is the infotainment class where PlaceListMapTemplate is used,
import android.location.Location
import androidx.car.app.CarContext
import androidx.car.app.Screen
import androidx.car.app.model.Action
import androidx.car.app.model.CarIcon
import androidx.car.app.model.CarLocation
import androidx.car.app.model.ItemList
import androidx.car.app.model.MessageTemplate
import androidx.car.app.model.Place
import androidx.car.app.model.PlaceListMapTemplate
import androidx.car.app.model.Row
import androidx.car.app.model.Template
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.ddainfotainment.RepositoryUtils.setUpObserversAndCallApi
import com.example.ddainfotainment.Utils.goToHome
import com.example.ddainfotainment.db.LocationEntity
import com.example.ddainfotainment.db.LocationViewModel
import com.example.ddainfotainment.db.LocationViewModelFactory
import com.example.ddainfotainment.db.MyApplication
import com.example.ddainfotainment.model.WeatherResModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class PlaceListMapExample4(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext),
    DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private var weatherResponseModelData: WeatherResModel? = null
    private var currentLocation: Location? = null
    private var mIsLoading = true
    private var errorMessage: String? = null

    private val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel

    init {
        val repository = (carContext.applicationContext as MyApplication).repository
        val factory = LocationViewModelFactory(repository)
        locationViewModel = ViewModelProvider(carContext as ViewModelStoreOwner, factory).get(LocationViewModel::class.java)

        // Insert sample location
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val location = LocationEntity(latitude = 37.7749, longitude = -122.4194, radius = 10F)
            locationViewModel.insertLocation(location)
        }

        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    private fun isLocationChanged(newLocation: Location): Boolean {
        return currentLocation?.run { latitude != newLocation.latitude || longitude != newLocation.longitude }
            ?: true
    }

    private val loadingCallback: (Boolean) -> Unit = { isLoading ->
        mIsLoading = isLoading
        if (isLoading) {
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    private val errorCallback: (String?) -> Unit = { errorData ->
        errorMessage = errorData
        invalidate()
    }

    private val weatherDataCallback: (WeatherResModel?) -> Unit = { weatherResponse ->
        weatherResponseModelData = weatherResponse
        mIsLoading = false
        errorMessage = null
        invalidate()
    }

    private val currentLocationCallback: (Location) -> Unit = { location ->
        if (isLocationChanged(location)) {
            currentLocation = location
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        setUpObserversAndCallApi(
            carContext,
            this,
            loadingCallback,
            errorCallback,
            weatherDataCallback,
            currentLocationCallback
        )

        val placeDetailRow = Row.Builder()
        weatherResponseModelData?.let {
            placeDetailRow.addText("${it.name}  ·  ${it.sys.country}")
        }

        val onClickListener: () -> Unit = {
            weatherResponseModelData?.let {
                screenManager.push(PlaceDetailsScreen(carContext, it))
            } ?: run {
                Utility.showErrorMessage(
                    carContext,
                    carContext.getString(R.string.loading_status)
                )
            }
        }

        val builder = PlaceListMapTemplate.Builder()
        if (mIsLoading) {
            return builder.run {
                setLoading(true)
                setTitle(carContext.getString(R.string.my_location))
                setHeaderAction(Action.BACK)
                build()
            }
        }

        errorMessage?.let {
            return MessageTemplate.Builder(it).run {
                setTitle(Constants.PLACE_LIST_MAP_TEMPLATE)
                setIcon(CarIcon.ERROR)
                setHeaderAction(Action.BACK)
                setActionStrip(goToHome(carContext, this@PlaceListMapExample4))
                addAction(RepositoryUtils.getRetryAction(carContext, this@PlaceListMapExample4))
                build()
            }
        }

        builder.setItemList(
            ItemList.Builder()
                .addItem(
                    placeDetailRow.run {
                        setTitle(carContext.getString(R.string.browse_place_details))
                        setBrowsable(true)
                        setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
                        build()
                    }
                )
                .build()
        )
            .setTitle(carContext.getString(R.string.my_location))
            .setHeaderAction(Action.BACK)

        currentLocation?.let {
            builder.setAnchor(
                Place.Builder(CarLocation.create(it)).build()
            )
        }
        return builder.build()
    }
}

below is the exception which I am getting,
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
    public abstract java.lang.Object getAllLocations(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Could any one please help me on this, thanks in Advance
